# How do you create a singly linked list with input in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

We were tasked with creating a linked list with the following output:

```
Enter number of nodes: 5

12 4 5 44 45

The linked list:

12 4 5 44 45
```

I am very confused with linked lists, with my code being the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    int nodeNumber;
    Node *next;
}*nodePtr=NULL,*nodeTemp=NULL,*nodeHead=NULL;

void addNode (int num, int nodeSize);
void displayNode();

int main(){
    int size, value;

    cout<<"Enter number of Nodes: ";
    cin>>size;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cin>>value;
        addNode(value,size);
        //These are just to check if the data is being stored correctly in the structs
        cout<<nodeTemp->data;
        cout<<nodePtr->data;
        cout<<nodeHead->data;
    }

    displayNode();
    system("pause>0");
}
 
void addNode(int num, int nodeSize){
    int i = 0;
    nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->data = num;
    nodePtr->next = NULL;

    if (nodePtr->next == NULL){
        nodeHead = nodePtr;
        nodeTemp = nodePtr;
        nodePtr->next = nodeTemp;
    }
    else
        while(i<nodeSize){
            nodeTemp->next = nodeTemp;
        }
        nodeTemp->next = NULL;
}

void displayNode(){
    nodeTemp = new Node;
    nodeTemp = nodeHead;
    
    cout<<"The linked list: ";
    while(nodeTemp != NULL){
        cout<<nodeTemp->data<<" ";
        nodeTemp = nodeTemp->next;
    }
}
```

The code however, only outputs the last value inputted. When I checked the data (see line 22,23,24), it seems that the node pointer, temp, and the head always have the same values. I am confused with what my mistakes might be, and any help would be very nice.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting this on debugger(gdb) and checking what is happening on each line of addNode? I see problem in this method.

Comment: Fyi, `nodeTemp = new Node; nodeTemp = nodeHead;` = memory leak in two lines. This isn't Java. You don't need to new *everything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pass the **size** variable to the **addNode** Function. Just take values as much you desire in main funtion and pass them to addNode funtion by looping till the size, then add Nodes to the list as usual.
Your code will look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    int nodeNumber;
    Node *next;
};
Node *nodeHead=NULL;

void addNode (int num);
void displayNode();

int main(){
    int size, value;

    cout<<"Enter number of Nodes: ";
    cin>>size;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cin>>value;
        addNode(value);
    }

    displayNode();
    system("pause>0");
}
 
void addNode(int num){
    Node *tail = nodeHead;
    Node *nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->data = num;
    nodePtr->next = NULL;

    if (nodeHead == NULL){
        nodeHead = nodePtr;
    }
    else{
        while(tail->next != NULL){
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        tail->next = nodePtr;
    }
}

void displayNode(){
    Node *nodeTemp = new Node;
    nodeTemp = nodeHead;
    
    cout<<"The linked list: ";
    while(nodeTemp != NULL){
        cout<<nodeTemp->data<<" ";
        nodeTemp = nodeTemp->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for `size` variable while you are inserting a node at the end of the list.

change your function like below:

```
void addNode(int num){
    nodePtr = new Node;
    nodePtr->data = num;
    nodePtr->next = NULL;
    /* if head is null, or list is empty! */
    if (nodeHead == NULL){
        nodeHead = nodePtr;
    }
    else{
        /* traverse the list to the end and add node at the NULL position */
        /* create a chain of nodeHead to nodeTemp */
        nodeTemp = nodeHead;
        while(nodeTemp-> next != NULL){
            nodeTemp = nodeTemp->next;
        }
        nodeTemp->next = nodePtr;
    }
}
```